# Запись структуры в файл с++ Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, структуры

Какая -то фигня. Ошибок при компиляции не выдает, но не работает. Я при записи создаю счетчик `ch++` что бы знать количество записей сохраненных в файле. Для того, что бы построить цикл вывода всех записей на консоль.
 `for(int i=0;i>ch;i++)`

Цель: создать функцию добавления сколько угодно записей в файл. И функцию просмотра всех записей. Как узнать сколько записей выводить на экран. Если в фале уже есть 2 записи и мы добавим еще 5. И задаюсь вопросом как устроить циклы для сортировки. и вообще с остальными циклами. Помогите разобраться.

```
struct rabotniki
    {
        char fio[20];
        int number;
        char pol[1];
        int godrozhd;
        int godpost;
    }rab[9];
    rabotniki temp;

    int main()
    {
        SetConsoleCP(1251);
        SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
        FILE * file;
        rabotniki rab[9];
        rabotniki temp;
        int n, ch = 0;
        file = fopen("file.bin", "wr");
        cout << "Введите количество работников : ";
        cin >> n;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {

        cout << "Введите ФИО " << i + 1 << " рабочего : ";
        gets_s(rab[i].fio);

        cout << "Введите пол: ";
        gets_s(rab[i].pol);

        cout << "Год рождения : ";
        cin >> rab[i].godrozhd;

        cout << "Год поступления на работу : ";
        cin >> rab[i].godpost;
        ch++;
        fwrite(&rab[i], sizeof(rab[i]), 1, file);
    }
    fclose(file);

    file = fopen("file.bin", "rb");
    cout << "Счетчик:" << ch;
    for (int i = 0; i < ch; i++)
    {
        fread(&rab[i], sizeof(rab[i]), 1, file);
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)

            for (int j = 0; j < n - 1; j++)

                if (rab[j].godrozhd < rab[j + 1].godrozhd)

                {
                    temp = rab[j];

                    rab[j] = rab[j + 1];

                    rab[j + 1] = temp;
                }
        printf("-----------------------------------------------------------\n");
        printf("|        ФИО       | Пол | Год рождения | Год поступления |\n");
        printf("-----------------------------------------------------------\n");
    }


    for (int i = 0; i < ch; i++)

        cout << rab[i].fio << "\t" << rab[i].pol << "\t" << rab[i].godrozhd << "\t" << rab[i].godpost << "\t" << "\n-----------------------------------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << endl << endl;
    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

И по моему я тут напортачил что-то с файлом. Исправьте, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

В курсовой работе  я делал у себя так, и это работает у меня. Я думаю вы сможете под себя переделать, я оставил ссылку на курсач, может там что интересного для себя найдете. Делал в среде Code::Blocks 16.01, и кстати в проекте есть сортировка, поиск и фильтрация данных.

```
//Запись в файл
    void RabotaAccount::wrt()
    {
       vector <person>::iterator iter1;
       ofstream file;
       file.open("GROUP.DAT", ios::trunc);
        int n = 0;
        iter1 = persVector.begin();
            while(iter1 != persVector.end())
            {
                cout << (*iter1);
                file.write( reinterpret_cast<char*>(&(*iter1)), sizeof((*iter1)) );
                *iter1++;
                n++;
            }
            cout << n <<endl;
        persVector.clear();
        file.close();
    }
```

И вывод данных

```
    //вывод данных в память
void RabotaAccount::readPolz()
{
    person pers;
    fstream file;
    persVector.clear();
    file.open("GROUP.DAT", ios::app | ios::out |
                                      ios::in);
    file.seekg(0);                 //reset to start of file
                                  //read first person
   file.read( reinterpret_cast<char*>(&pers), sizeof(pers) );
   while( !file.eof() )           //quit on EOF
      {
             //display person
      persVector.push_back(pers);
               //read another person
      file.read( reinterpret_cast<char*>(&pers), sizeof(pers) );
      }
    file.close();
}
```

[Курсач, логин: admin, пароль: 123](http://dropmefiles.com/jefnj)

Пример сортировки у меня, через вектор

```
    void Taksopark::sortAvto()
{
     vector <AvtoTaksopark>::iterator iter1;
     readPolz();
     char ch;
     char c;
     do
     {
     do
     {
     system("cls");
     cout << "-------------Сортировка по названию-------------\n";
     cout << "Выберите вид сортировки (>/<): ";
     cin >> ch;

     if(ch == '>')
     {
         sort(avtoVector.begin(), avtoVector.end(), SortNazvanie());
     }
     else if (ch == '<')
     {
     sort(avtoVector.begin(), avtoVector.end(), SortNazvanie2());
 }
 else
 {
     cout << "Не правильный ввод";
     break;
 }
    iter1 = avtoVector.begin();
    while(iter1 != avtoVector.end())
        {(*iter1++).getAvtoStoimost();
        cout << "\n\n";
        }
 }
 while(ch == '>' && ch == '<');
    char a;
    cout << "Записать в файл? (y/n): ";
    cin >> a;

    if(a == 'y')
    {
        cout << "Данные файла перезаписаны\n";
        write();
    }

    cout << "Для прололжения нажмите (y/n): ";
    cin >> c;
 }
 while(c == 'y');
```

}

и классы предикаты для этого

```
    class SortNazvanie
{
    public:
        bool operator()(AvtoTaksopark &avto1, AvtoTaksopark &avto2) const
        {
           return (strcmp(avto1.getAvtoBase().getAvto(),avto2.getAvtoBase().getAvto()) == 1) ? true : false;
        }
};


class SortNazvanie2
{
    public:
        bool operator()(AvtoTaksopark &avto1, AvtoTaksopark &avto2) const
        {
           return (strcmp(avto1.getAvtoBase().getAvto(),avto2.getAvtoBase().getAvto()) == -1) ? true : false;
        }
};
```